# Passing a String to Java Class from Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I need to pass a string value from my main activity to a Java class that implements a BroadcastReceiver. Basically I want to get a String value from an EditText in AddNewPrescriptionsActivity.java and pass it to AlarmReceiver.java. It seems that I can't use an Intent or a Bundle to pass it so is there another way to do this?? I have some of my code below..

Here is some of my MainActivity called AddNewPrescriptionsActivity.java:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btnSave) {
        calSet.getTime();
        if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
        //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        setAlarm(calSet);
        Toast.makeText(AddNewPrescriptionsActivity.this, "Notification Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }


    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

Here is my AlarmReceiver.class which implements BroadcastReceiver

```
   public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(arg0, notification);
        r.play();

        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Received" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question well, you need to send a String value from your Activity to your Broadcast Receiver. To do this, in your Activity:

```
    Intent in = new Intent("my.action.string");
    in.putExtra("state", "activated");
    sendBroadcast(in);
```

And inside the BroadcastReceiver :

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  String action = intent.getAction();

  Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);

  if(action.equals("my.action.string")){
     String state = intent.getExtras().getString("state");
     //do your stuff
  }
}
```

And inside the manifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".YourBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    <action android:name="my.action.string" />
    <!-- and some more actions if you want -->
</intent-filter>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This looks like it might be helpful, however it is still crashing when I run it. I'll edit my question to try to be more specific.

Comment: If it does crash! tell what you obtain in log cat!